# Subdomain and it's folder rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's explain my issues. I have folder which contains subdomain files.

Folder which contains subdomain files is called "subdomain".

My domain is `example.com`.

My subdomain is `sub.example.com`.

Issue is that when I type `https://sub.example.com` it works but same content is loaded when I type `https://example.com/subdomain` or `https://sub.example.com/subdomain`

My question is, how to achieve that `https://example.com/subdomain(.*)` will redirect to `https://sub.example.com(.*)` and same with `https://sub.example.com/subdomain(.*)` that will redirect to `https://sub.example.com(.*)`

Current .htaccess configuration is as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /subdomain/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule as your **topmost** rule inside your site root .htaccess or in `subdomain/.htaccess`:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# use THE_REQUEST to detect presence of /subdomain/ in original URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+subdomain/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://sub.example.com/%1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of other rewrite directives. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`